# How is the anomaly applied to an individual in the matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

The Architect says:

> **Your life is the sum of a remainder of an unbalanced equation inherent
>   to the programming of the matrix.** You are the eventuality of an
>   anomaly, which despite my sincerest efforts I have been unable to
>   eliminate from what is otherwise a harmony of mathematical precision. 
>   **While it remains a burden to sedulously avoid it, it is not unexpected, and thus not beyond a measure of control. Which has led you, inexorably, here.**

**Questions**:

1. Is the anomaly is the reason why someone in the matrix will eventually become the One?
2. How exactly is the anomaly applied to an individual in the matrix to become the One?

Was the anomaly embedded into Neo's RSI? Was it just waiting to be unlocked after he died (like when an update says you have to restart for it to take effect)?

I found [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93518/124499) answer, but it doesn't fully answer what I'm asking.

Comment: Think of it as the leap year solution. Since the Earth's tour around the sun doesn't last EXACTLY 365 days, we add an extra day every 4 years, but that's still not exact, so every 100 years we don't add that extra day, but that's still not exact so we add.....and so on, and so on, until you have enough "rounding" error for a full day.

Comment: I think the anomaly is Neo and that the architect controls the anomaly by giving it the illusion of 'choice'. Further, the Architect fashions the one in such a way that he/she has an overriding 'love', which expressed itself in the past as a love of mankind - but in this particular run through it's expressed itself as love for an individual person (Trinity).